# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Page declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I am having an issue with an existing site that was functioning until last week. When I open the site in VS 2013 I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error/warning on the page declaration of the `.aspx` pages and `.master` pages. The website builds correctly but when run only displays a blank page and no errors.

I have verified that the code behind file exists and it's namespace and class are properly entered into the page declaration. Adding a new page to the project gets the same error and I have verified the references are all present. The website is with 3.5 framework. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Clayton

[image: Image of error message]

Comment: is the ajax control toolkit properly loaded/referenced in visual studio? the object in question could be from the toolkit.

Comment: The application had a reference to the Ajax Control Toolkit. I removed the reference and installed version 7.1005.0 (The application use the 3.5 framework) but I am still getting the same error. Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wasn't making any headway in getting this resolved I decided to create a new web project and move all the existing files into the new project. I decided to do this one file at a time to see if I could nail down the page or setting causing the issue. All the files copied over and the site ran as expected until I started to tweek the web config file to match some of the settings from the old project. Everything worked until I added the line

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\Username" password="Password" />
```

Once I saved and ran the webpage I started getting the same errors from the other project. Commenting out this line resolved the issue for me but now I've got to figure out why that would cause such a strange issue.

Thanks everyone for their time.

Edit: Oddly enough the line works without specifying the user account so if I put `<identity impersonate="true" />` then everything works as expected.

Comment: what line did you add? it's missing in your post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what happened there. I have edited the answer to include the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(it looks like you have done this already but) the only other thing i can see is that 'CodeBehind' usually matches 'Inherits'. it doesn't have to match but make sure that 'Inherits'

```
... Inherits="_default"
```

matches the code behind's partial class:

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

your page's 'Inherits' says **RenewTemplate.Default**. does that exactly match the code behind?

Comment: It does match but thanks for the tip. It might help someone else. My issue seems to be with impersonation.